# .htaccess - Clashing rules causing internal server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm tying to add a section to our website which is heavily powered by a .htaccess file.

Currently I have a rule which handles rewrites if there is only one part after the domain so something like the following will cause the site to search for a page called 'theteam'.

https://very-pc.co.uk/theteam

This works well but I'm now trying to add a section which will have the following address:

https://very-pc.co.uk/products

The trouble is when I add a rule for this (making sure it's above the previous rule) it causes a 500 Internal Server Error. If I have one rule or the other it works perfectly but the problem comes when both rules are present.

It's a little hard to explain so here is the problem code:

```
RewriteRule ^products/?$                        ?cat=top-level-summary&page=products [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$                         /?cat=generic&page=$1 [QSA]
```

And the full .htaccess file:

```
# Error Handling
ErrorDocument 403                               /index.php?cat=error&page=403
ErrorDocument 404                               /index.php?cat=error&page=404
ErrorDocument 500                               /index.php?cat=error&page=500
ErrorDocument 503                               ?cat=error&page=503

# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden
Options                                         +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -        indexes -MultiViews

# Turn the rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine                                   On

# Set the root of the folder to structure
ReWriteBase                                     /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Start the mod re-write conditions
# Redirect short URLs
RewriteRule ^broadleaf/?$                       /products/desktops/broadleaf-one    [R=301]
RewriteRule ^broadleafone/?$                    /products/desktops/broadleaf-one    [R=301]
RewriteRule ^broadleaf-one/?$                   /products/desktops/broadleaf-one    [R=301]
RewriteRule ^flex/?$                            /products/desktops/flex             [R=301]
RewriteRule ^fmq/?$                             /fixmequick                         [R=301]
RewriteRule ^warranty/?$                        /productregistration                [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}                 !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}                 !-d

# Redirect the specific categories
RewriteRule ^products/?$                        ?cat=top-level-summary&page=products [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$                         /?cat=generic&page=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$          ?cat=product&page=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/?$                /?cat=product-section-summary&page=$1 [QSA]

# Redirects for blog
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)$                      ?cat=blog&page=$1
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([^/]+)$             ?cat=blog_archive_or_category&blog_cat=$1
RewriteRule ^blog/archive/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$      ?cat=blog_archive_or_category&year=$1&month=$2

# Redirect the browser to the https:// version of the domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}                            !on
RewriteRule (.*)                                https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

# Disable hot-linking of files on the server
# (other sites cannot link to our images and steal our bandwidth)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}                     !^$

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}                    !very-pc\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}                     !verypc\.very-dev\.co\.uk [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}                     ^http://(cms\.)?very-pc\.co\.uk/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}                     ^http://(cms\.)?very-dev\.co\.uk/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|pdf)$                - [F,NC]

# Redirect to remove /index.php and /index.html files
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}                      \ /(.+/)?index\.(php|html)(\?.*)?\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index\.(php|html)$           /%1 [NC,R=301,L,QSA]
```

As I said, I've tried just having one line or the other present and it works so my best guess is that those two rules are clashing somehow.

I've tried messing around with the parameters i.e changing it to a redirect or adding [L] to make it stop after the first line is met but I've had no luck.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Is there anything useful in the error logs?

Comment: [Thu Aug 14 12:24:05 2014] [error] [client 78.109.178.130] File does not exist: /home/verypcco/public_html/autodiscover - not sure if this is related?

Comment: This is one scary .htaccess, if you reduce it down to just the problem area I can investigate but at present it is pretty big.

Comment: @anubhava Tell me about it! It was written by someone else and to be honest I only have a working knowledge of it. I'm also unfortunately in a rush to get this completed. I've removed unused and unneeded lines - any help you could give would be massively appreciated!

Comment: ok I dared to rearrange the rules and fix the missing directives. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
# Error Handling
ErrorDocument 403                               /index.php?cat=error&page=403
ErrorDocument 404                               /index.php?cat=error&page=404
ErrorDocument 500                               /index.php?cat=error&page=500
ErrorDocument 503                               ?cat=error&page=503

# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -indexes -MultiViews

# Turn the rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine On
# Set the root of the folder to structure
ReWriteBase /

# Disable hot-linking of files on the server
# (other sites cannot link to our images and steal our bandwidth)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}                     !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}                     !verypc\.very-dev\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}                     ^http://(cms\.)?very-pc\.co\.uk/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}                     ^http://(cms\.)?very-dev\.co\.uk/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|pdf)$                - [F,NC]

# Redirect the browser to the https:// version of the domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Redirect to remove /index.php and /index.html files
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+?/)?index\.(php|html)(\?.*)?\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index\.(php|html)$           /%1 [NC,R=301,L,NE]

# Start the mod re-write conditions
# Redirect short URLs
RewriteRule ^broadleaf/?$                       /products/desktops/broadleaf-one    [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^broadleafone/?$                    /products/desktops/broadleaf-one    [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^broadleaf-one/?$                   /products/desktops/broadleaf-one    [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^flex/?$                            /products/desktops/flex             [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fmq/?$                             /fixmequick                         [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^warranty/?$                        /productregistration                [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Redirect the specific categories
RewriteRule ^products/?$ ?cat=top-level-summary&page=products [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ ?cat=product&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/?$ ?cat=product-section-summary&page=$1 [L,QSA]

# Redirects for blog
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/$ ?cat=blog&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([^/]+)$ ?cat=blog_archive_or_category&blog_cat=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/archive/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  ?cat=blog_archive_or_category&year=$1&month=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?cat=generic&page=$1 [L,QSA]
```